# how to implement database record authorization with ldap in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap, entity-framework-5

I have a layered application of invoices management, the presentation layer is a asp.net mvc 4 project,i use entity framework for database access. the invoices are stored in oracle database. and i want to apply LDAP authentication on that application,i haven't any idea, i want from you to guide me ,please, to implement an authorization so that:

- the user that have role admin can view/ create/ edit/delete all
  invoices.
- and the other authenticated users, every one, can only view /create
  /edit/ delete the invoices that belong of its Department or
  subordinated Departments of its Department.

any help? i would appreciate that.